# Read 64bit Hex value from a file in C

Tags: c, file-io

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
0000000000000000    0000000000000000
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF    FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
3000000000000000    1000000000000001
1111111111111111    1111111111111111
0123456789ABCDEF    1111111111111111
1111111111111111    0123456789ABCDEF
0808080808080808    0000000000000000
FEDCBA9876543210    0123456789ABCDEF
7CA110454A1A6E57    01A1D6D039776742
0131D9619DC1376E    5CD54CA83DEF57DA
```

What would be the best way to read these in using C? My first attempt tried to use `fscanf()` to read them into `int` variables, but these are 64-bit hex values, so the `int` type is too small to read them in completely and part of the values were truncated.

My attempt:

```
while( fscanf(infile, "%x %x", &key, &plaintext) != EOF )
{
    printf("%x\t\t%x\n", key, plaintext);

}
```

Is there a type large enough to hold this in C? If not what are my other options for storage? Char arrays?

Thanks

Please note that I am using ANSI C, with GCC 4.5.2 (MinGW)

Comment: If `long` is 8 bytes wide on your platform (and you don't care about other platforms), you could scan for `%lx` and use a `long` instead (or unsigned, if you prefer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the macro and typedef from `inttypes.h`:

```
uint64_t key,plaintext;
fscanf(infile,"%u" PRIx64 " %u" PRIx64,&key, &plaintext);
```

Comment: When I try to use this macro with `printf("%u" PRIx64, key)`. It prints the value of the key, but then follows it with "Ix64", any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

In C99, C11 and C++11, you can use `strtoull`, e.g. `strtoull(s, NULL, 16);`, from the header `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: How can I tell if my compiler can compile C99? To my knowledge I have never used that dialect of C

Comment: Read the manual, I guess. In GCC you can pass `-std=c99`, or `c1x`, or (soon) `c11`. It's not so much a "dialect" as it is a "version". (`gnu99` would be a "dialect", or `-fno-exceptions` in C++.)

Comment: GCC 4.5.2 will support `-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99`.  Either will give you `long long` support, which gives you at least 64-bit integers.

Comment: (@HunterMcMillen: It's a bit shocking really that even 12 years after publication of C99, people still prefer the 22-year old version!)

Comment: @KerrekSB This is for a project I am working on, I have to use whatever the instructor asks for.

Comment: @KerrekSB If I did decide to use `strtoull` how would I point it at a file? Would I have to read the input into a `char*` first then call `strtoull`?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: yes, indeed. The `fscanf` approach is probably easier. I just never liked `scanf`, so I didn't think of it :-)